# Delete all files in /var/opt/mssql/log everyday?

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu-18.04

I want to delete it regularly every day, is there a problem with my database if I delete it every day?

Because if left unchecked it will take up very large space
see this pic below (I use ubuntu server):

[image: log_pic]

Comment: You could also execute `sp_cycle_errorlog` periodically (daily?) on SQL itself.

Comment: what for sp_cycle_errorlog, I don't even know how to use it? 
can I delete it in the MSSMS editor?

Comment: It is a SQL system stored procedure that recycles the log. On Windows installations this is run periodically (daily) and prevents the infinite log growth you see on your linux box. Is run just like any other SQL command, from a SQL client.

Comment: thank you remus with this amazing answer, you saved my life!

Comment: I ran this as logs were taking up 14GB of space but there are 128 log files in this folder at around 100MB each and it would appear each time it is run it clears one of these taking it down to just a few bytes - first time it is run errorlog is cleared, next time errorlog.1 is cleared, next time errorlog.2 is cleared etc. So this would seem to involve running this command 128 times. Is this correct? Is there a reason it is like this as it is just a default Ubuntu install and I didn't change any defaults that I remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to delete it.

This directory contains only logs and does not hold the main data of your database.

Answer (score 1):

you can configure the number of error logs for your SQL Server instance

(default behavior in SQL Server on Linux is to keep 128 error logs)

if you want to retain 6 error logs in the LOG folder, you will configure it as follows:

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set errorlog.numerrorlogs 6
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-mssql-conf?view=sql-server-ver15#errorlogdir

Comment: nice, thank you @abd-alrazak. for the alternative